when I console.log fetched data it appears as undefined but it appears when I refresh
I have this function in react to fetch the data from my django API:
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState([]);

const fetchFilterData = async () => {
    const filter_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filters/'
    try {
      const response = await fetch(filter_url)
      const result = await response.json();
      setFilterData(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error fetching data: ', error);
    }


  }

and when I try to console.log the data it is shown as undefined at first but if I change something in the code (like add a white space or a new line) and save the fetched data appears and everything works fine but the issue is that I can't render that data or pass it down as a prop to other components
Here's the useEffect hook:
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchFilterData();
  }, []);

and I have tried logging the data in several ways but no use it always returns undefined at first. Here are several ways I have tried:
import React from 'react'
import './Home.css'
// import { listOfHouses } from './mock-data'
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import PopupTextBox from '../../Components/PopupTextBox/PopupTextBox'
import DropDown from '../../Components/DropDown/DropDown'

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState([]);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState('asc');

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const houseList_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000//api/listings?price__lt=&price__gt=&apartment__block_name=&apartment__floor=&apartment__type=&apartment__view=&status=&type=';
    const result = await fetch(houseList_url);
    result.json().then(json => setData(json));
    // console.log(data)
  }

  const fetchFilterData = async () => {
    const filter_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filters/'
    try {
      const response = await fetch(filter_url)
      const result = await response.json();
      setFilterData(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error fetching data: ', error);
    }

    if(filterData) {console.log(filterData)} else {console.log("data is not defined")};

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchFilterData().then(console.log(filterData));
  }, []);

  const sorting = (col) => {
    if (order === 'asc') {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() > b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
      setOrder('desc');
      setData(sorted);
    }
    if (order === 'desc') {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() < b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
      setOrder('asc');
      setData(sorted);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='h-full grid grid-rows-[max-content_1fr]'>
      <div className='h-28 bg-blue-500 text-center'>
        <button className='button bg-teal-700' onClick={fetchData}>fetch</button>
        <div>
          {filterData && <DropDown people={filterData.all_blocks} />}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='bg-white'>
        <table className='table-auto w-full'>
          <thead className='bg-gray-300'>
          , , , , , , , , 

edit:
here's a more complete snippet of the code I am running

Which console.log() and where does it show you undefined? Give a more complete code example so that it is clear exactly what you are doing and what is not working.

I have provided a more complete snippet of the code @SwaD

Duplicate of The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

@GuyIncognito Thank you for the answer and I have just tried this approach and I don't know if it's supposed to be this way but putting setFilterData(prevData => ([...prevData, ...results]) gives me TypeError: result is not iterable and another issue is using useEffect(() => {     fetchData();     fetchFilterData();   }, [fitlerData]); results in the function getting called over and over without stopping and I don't know if that's the way it should be

You don't need to change anything. The code works as intended, just use the filterData as needed. If you need it in the fetchFilterData function, use result instead.

it was because const [fitlerData, setFilterData] = useState([])
and not const [fitlerData, setFilterData] = useState()
which means when I did something like {filterData && <DropDown people={filterData.all_blocks} />}  it passed the empty list and didn't wait until the data has actually been fetched.
Now the code looks something like this:
export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState();
  const [order, setOrder] = useState('asc');

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const houseList_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000//api/listings?price__lt=&price__gt=&apartment__block_name=&apartment__floor=&apartment__type=&apartment__view=&status=&type=';
    const result = await fetch(houseList_url);
    result.json().then(json => setData(json));
  }

  const fetchFilterData = async () => {
    const filter_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filters/'
    try {
      const response = await fetch(filter_url)
      const result = await response.json();
      setFilterData(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error fetching data: ', error);
    }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchFilterData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    filterData ? console.log(filterData) : console.log('loading...')
  }, [filterData]);

  const sorting = (col) => {
    if (order === 'asc') {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() > b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
      setOrder('desc');
      setData(sorted);
    }
    if (order === 'desc') {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() < b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
      setOrder('asc');
      setData(sorted);
    }
  }

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    fetchData();
    fetchFilterData();
  }

  return (
    <div className='h-full grid grid-rows-[max-content_1fr]'>
      <div className='h-28 bg-blue-500 text-center'>
        <button className='button bg-teal-700' onClick={handleRefresh}>fetch</button>
        <div>
          {filterData
            ? <Fragment>
              <DropDown items={filterData.all_blocks} />
            </Fragment>
            : <div>loading...</div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>

I hate JavaScript :)
